# Banning users from Facebook group

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, userscripts

I'm developing a userscript in which I want to place a "ban member" button next to every post on a group's timeline. I've already coded a way to get post author's UID and place the button, but how to ban a member from a group? Is there any way to do so? Graph API is not working for me in this case.

Comment: That functionality already exists in the FB UI, so why would it need an extra script for that?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook API doesn't let you ban users via their API - basically your only option is writing a script that opens a browser and does that for you. You can do it with something headless, like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).